# Multiple web sites with virtual hosts not working

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to use the built in apache web server (2.4) in Mac OSX 10.11.2 to locally develop a website separate from the default website.  I believe this can be done using name-based virtual hosts.  So I changed my `/etc/hosts` file to have the line

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.0.1    testwebsite.com
```

and I edited my httpd.conf file to use the vhosts file in `/extra`:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and I edited the `httpd-vhosts.conf` to look like this:

```
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<Directory "/Users/me/testwebsite/DocRoot">                                  
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews                                            
    MultiviewsMatch Any 
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted                                                  
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/testwebsite/DocRoot"
    ServerName testwebsite.com
    ErrorLog "/Users/me/testwebsite/error-log"
    CustomLog "/Users/me/testwebsite/access-log" common
</VirtualHost>

#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
#    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
#    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
#    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
#    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
#</VirtualHost>
```

But requests in the browser all go to the new document root. Aka I'd like requests to `localhost` to give a "It works!" html file from the server's default document root, while serving files from the new document root only for requests to `testwebsite.com`.

Comment: Did you restart your apache service to let your change become effective?

Comment: I've done `sudo apachectl restart`, `sudo apachectl -k stop` then `sudo apachectl start`, but nothing works.  Recently, I added `ServerName localhost` to the httpd.conf file, but that didn't work.  Now I get a '403: forbidden' response when going to `localhost` in the browser, even after deleting the `ServerName` line and restarting/starting & stopping the server.

Comment: Edited question: new issue now (all requests go to the new DocumentRoot instead of only the matched `ServerName` in the `VirtualHost` directive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a VirtualHost section for each virtual host you want to serve up.
So add another Virtual Host section and modify those entries accordingly.

Altogether you would have something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
DocumentRoot "/the/other/path/DocRoot"
ServerName localhost
ErrorLog "/other/path/error-log"
CustomLog "/other/path/access-log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
DocumentRoot "/Users/me/testwebsite/DocRoot"
ServerName testwebsite.com
ErrorLog "/Users/me/testwebsite/error-log"
CustomLog "/Users/me/testwebsite/access-log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

The trick is to use the ServerName correctly, which you have done. That and the hosts file hack, a restart of Apache and you should be good.